# Using azure stream analytics with power BI

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

I have created a stream analytic's job in Azure. I want to use Power BI as the output of the stream job. But seems that only azure accounts with organizational Id can be used there. Is there is any workaround to use Azure stream analytic with power BI using azure account without organizational ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is no workaround. Power BI only allows organizational IDs to login.

Are you an admin of the default directory of Azure Active Directory? Just create an new user@mydirectory.onmicrosoft.com and sign up for free at powerbi.com with that user.

Edit: just today they resolved this limitation in Azure Stream Analytics:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/streamanalytics/archive/2015/07/31/new-asa-features-service-bus-queues-and-topics-outputs-amp-power-bi-org-id-decoupled-from-azure-id.aspx

Comment: Great to See this . Thanks GregGalloway :)